# Authenticated POST in Python for insert into Google Fusion Tables

Tags: python, post, insert, google-fusion-tables

Apologies if this is basic stuff - I have been trying for a while to successfully send an authenticated POST to Google Fusion Tables to test an insert into a private table.

Have read examples and libraries in fusion tables documentation - but the examples seem to typically be selects (vs. inserts) and the libraries that are available for Python do not seem to work with OAuth 2.0.

I have successfully -

1. Authenticated with OAuth 2.0.  Have Access Token and Refresh Token.
2. I can do selects on a private table with the following code straight out of the Google examples:

   ```
   request = urllib2.Request(
   url='https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?%s' % \
   (urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token,
                      'sql': 'SELECT * FROM 1cRYFfBB_nA0qUSAe6R8vI96G2yxIULrX92FOum4'})))
   request_open = urllib2.urlopen(request)
   response = request_open.read()
   request_open.close()
   print response
   ```

With the following code for a POST

```
import httplib, urllib, urllib2
query = 'INSERT INTO 1cRYFfBB_nA0qUSAe6R8vI96G2yxIULrX92FOum4 (locations, strings, numbers) VALUES (1,2,3);'
data = urllib.urlencode({'sql': query})
URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'
headers = {
      'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=' + access_token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    serv_req = urllib2.Request(url=URL, data=data, headers=headers)
    serv_resp = urllib2.urlopen(serv_req)
```

I get HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

This is right after I can run a Select on a private table with the same access_token - I am assuming I have a code or sytax issue.

Also - I am a Python newbie and Fusion Tables newbie - thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

requests-oauth may be worth a look: https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth

Comment: Hi - thanks for the advice - the requests-oauth looks awesome but I think that it uses OAuth 1.0.

Comment: Hi folks - any other helpful comments out there - am still stuck

Comment: I am as well interested in a simple example to authenticate and read/write a fusion table.